# equals method for DoublyLinkedList

Tags: java, equals, doubly-linked-list

I got this assignment to create an equals method for doubly linked list. So far I got the code I posted below. It passes some of the tests, but not all. The failures do have the same expected value as the actual value, but I still get some AssertionErrors.

Ive been messing and trying to change things for quite some time now, but I cant seem to figure it out on my own. Nor can I find any good examples on the internet. I've tried using Eclipse to generate the equals method, but that too does not pass all the tests.

I know you do not give away free answers here, but could someone maybe point to the mistake in the code?

```
    /**
     * This method should return true iff the values of this list 
     * and that are identical and in the same order.
     * @param that list to compare this to.
     * @return true iff the values are identical and in the same order
     */
    public boolean equals(Object that) {
      if (that == null)
        return false;
      if (!(that instanceof DoublyLinkedList) )
    return false;

  DoublyLinkedList<E> other = (DoublyLinkedList<E>) that;
  if (header == null&&other.header != null)
            return false;
        if (trailer == null&&other.trailer != null)
            return false;           

  while (header.getNext() != trailer){
      if (!(header.equals(other.header))){
              return false;
      }
              header = header.getNext();
              other.header = other.header.getNext();
     }
        return true;
    }
```

Edit, per request the failed tests en DLL class:

```
public static class DoublyLinkedList<E> {
    private Node<E> header;
    private Node<E> trailer;

    /** 
     * Constructor that creates an empty DLL
     */
    public DoublyLinkedList() {
        this.header = new Node<>(null, null, null);
        this.trailer = new Node<>(null, header, null);
        this.header.setNext(trailer);
    }

    /**
     * @return if the list is empty.
     */
    public boolean isEmpty() {
      return this.header.getNext() == this.trailer;
    }

    /**
     * @return the first element of the list.
     */
    public E getFirst() {
      if (isEmpty()) return null;
        return this.header.getNext().getElement();
    }

    /**
     * @return the last element of the list.
     */
    public E getLast() {
      if (isEmpty()) return null;
        return this.trailer.getPrevious().getElement();
    }


    /**
     * Adds a new Node to the beginning of the list, 
     * containing the specified value.
     * @param value for the new first node to hold.
     */
    public void addFirst(E element) {
        Node<E> newNode = new Node<>(element, header, header.getNext());
        header.getNext().setPrevious(newNode);
        header.setNext(newNode);
    }

    /**
     * This method should return true iff the values of this list 
     * and that are identical and in the same order.
     * @param that list to compare this to.
     * @return true iff the values are identical and in the same order
     */
    public boolean equals(Object that) {
      if (that == null)
        return false;
      if (!(that instanceof DoublyLinkedList) )
    return false;

  DoublyLinkedList<E> other = (DoublyLinkedList<E>) that;
  if (header == null&&other.header != null)
            return false;
        if (trailer == null&&other.trailer != null)
            return false;           

  while (header.getNext() != trailer){
      if (!(header.equals(other.header))){
              return false;
      }
              header = header.getNext();
              other.header = other.header.getNext();
     }
        return true;
    }


    /**
     * Simple toString for testing purposes. Please note that solutions that use the
     * .toString() to implement the .equals() method will be rejected.
     */
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("DoublyLinkedList<");

        Node<E> finger = header.getNext();
        while (finger != trailer) {
            sb.append(finger.toString());
            if (finger.getNext() != trailer) {
                sb.append("-");
            }
            finger = finger.getNext();
        }

        sb.append(">");
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

And the tests:

```
@Test
    public void testEqualsCopy() {
        Solution.DoublyLinkedList<Integer> dll1 = createDLL(2);
        Solution.DoublyLinkedList<Integer> dll2 = createDLL(2);
        assertEquals(dll1, dll2);
    }
        @Test
    // Both lists contain only the entry 42.
    public void testTwoEqualLists() {
        Solution.DoublyLinkedList<Integer> dll1 = new Solution.DoublyLinkedList<>();
        Solution.DoublyLinkedList<Integer> dll2 = new Solution.DoublyLinkedList<>();
        dll1.addFirst(42);
        dll2.addFirst(42);
        assertEquals(dll1, dll2);
    }
```

and the errors:

```
testEqualsCopy(UTest) failed: 'java.lang.AssertionError: expected: Solution$DoublyLinkedList<DoublyLinkedList<1-0>> but was: Solution$DoublyLinkedList<DoublyLinkedList<1-0>>'
testTwoEqualLists(UTest) failed: 'java.lang.AssertionError: expected: Solution$DoublyLinkedList<DoublyLinkedList<42>> but was: Solution$DoublyLinkedList<DoublyLinkedList<42>>'
```

Comment: Well phrased question. Can you provide the tests that are failing? Also provide the code for the DoublyLinkedList class.

Comment: "I know you do not give away free answers here" Has somebody charged you for answering?

Comment: @SMA He wasn't referring to money but time spent answering a question.

Comment: @Zouter, At least you are looking for help and understanding as opposed to others who are asking people on here for us to do their assignments for them!!!

Answer (score 2):

Since, there's quite a gap between what I think a doubly linked list should look like and what you have, I would like to add my sample implementation instead. It does away with the dummy *header* and *trailer* nodes which IMHO aren't required at all.

```
public class DoublyLinkedList<E> {

    private Node<E> header;
    private Node<E> trailer;

    /**
     * @return if the list is empty.
     */
    public boolean isEmpty() {
      return header == null;
    }

    /**
     * @return the first element of the list.
     */
    public E getFirst() {
        return header != null ? header.getElement() : null;
    }

    /**
     * @return the last element of the list.
     */
    public E getLast() {
        return trailer != null ? trailer.getElement() : null;
    }

    /**
     * Adds a new Node to the beginning of the list, 
     * containing the specified value.
     * @param value for the new first node to hold.
     */
    public void addFirst(E element) {
        Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>(element, null, header);
        header = newNode;
        if (trailer == null) {
            trailer = newNode;
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method should return true if the values of this list and that are
     * identical and in the same order.
     * 
     * @param that
     *            list to compare this to.
     * @return true if the values are identical and in the same order
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public boolean equals(Object that) {
        if (!(that instanceof DoublyLinkedList))
            return false;

        DoublyLinkedList<E> other = (DoublyLinkedList<E>) that;

        // if lists are empty 
        if (header == null) {
            return other.header == null ? true : false;
        }

        if (!header.equals(other.header))
            return false;

        // Just one element
        if (header == trailer) {
            return true;
        }

        if (!trailer.equals(other.trailer))
            return false;

        Node<E> thisNode = header;
        Node<E> otherNode = other.header;

        while (thisNode.getNext() != trailer) {
            thisNode = thisNode.getNext();
            otherNode = otherNode.getNext();
            if (!(thisNode.equals(otherNode))) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }


    /**
     * Simple toString for testing purposes. Please note that solutions that use the
     * .toString() to implement the .equals() method will be rejected.
     */
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("DoublyLinkedList<");

        Node<E> finger = header;
        while (finger != null) {
            sb.append(finger.toString());
            if (finger.getNext() != null) {
                sb.append("-");
            }
            finger = finger.getNext();
        }

        sb.append(">");
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Here's what my `Node` class looks like. Not many changes here.

```
public class Node<E> {

    private E element;
    private Node<E> previous;
    private Node<E> next;

    public Node<E> getPrevious() {
        return previous;
    }

    public Node<E> getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public E getElement() {
        return element;
    }

    public Node(E element, Node<E> previous, Node<E> next) {
        this.element = element;
        this.previous = previous;
        this.next = next;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public boolean equals(Object that) {
        if (!(that instanceof Node)) {
            return false;
        }
        Node<E> other = (Node<E>) that;
        if (element == null) {
            return other.element == null ? true : false;
        }
        return element.equals(other.element);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return element.toString();
    }
}
```

Here's the code I used to test my implementation.

```
DoublyLinkedList<Integer> dll1 = new DoublyLinkedList<Integer>();
dll1.addFirst(100);
dll1.addFirst(200);

DoublyLinkedList<Integer> dll2 = new DoublyLinkedList<Integer>();
dll2.addFirst(100);
dll2.addFirst(200);

DoublyLinkedList<Integer> dll3 = new DoublyLinkedList<Integer>();
dll3.addFirst(42);

DoublyLinkedList<String> blankList1 = new DoublyLinkedList<String>();
DoublyLinkedList<String> blankList2 = new DoublyLinkedList<String>();

if (blankList1.equals(blankList2)) {
    System.out.println(blankList1 + " = " + blankList2);
}

if (!dll1.equals(dll3)) {
    System.out.println(dll1 + " != " + dll3);
}

if (dll1.equals(dll2)) {
    System.out.println(dll1 + " = " + dll2);
}
```

***Output :***

```
DoublyLinkedList<> = DoublyLinkedList<>
DoublyLinkedList<200-100> != DoublyLinkedList<42>
DoublyLinkedList<200-100> = DoublyLinkedList<200-100>
```

Comment: First of all thanks for you elaborate answer, but since I use equals(Object other) instead of equals(DoublyLinkedList other) I still need to cast using DoublyLinkedList<E> other = (DoublyLinkedList<E>) that; or change parameter. Right? Also i tried to rewrite the entire equals using your steps, but still fails the tests.

Comment: Ah, that was a gross oversight on my part. Corrected.

Comment: Actually, there's a lot of gap between what I thought your doubly linked list would look like. For example, even your empty linked list contains two Nodes which IMHO isn't required at all. Just two Node references would have done the job.

Comment: @Zouter Added my own sample doubly linked list implementation.

Comment: That is all code provided by the professor, this specific assigment was just to implement an equals method. Its all pretty new to me, for now.

Comment: I just tried a little testing with if-statements. If I just an if statement like(if(dll1.equals(dll2), it prints the line just fine, but on the next line assertEquals(dll1, dll2), failed. Ill just try schedual a meeting with the professor. Thank you for your extensive help.